# Docker: Getting, Component CommunityInstaller.AutoStartAction failed: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation

Tags: windows, docker

While installing Docker 4.2.0 on my Windows 10 Enterprise system,
I am getting following error:

```
Component CommunityInstaller.AutoStartAction failed: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoProcessAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
```

for the installation logs, please find attached image:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my system antivirus access permission issue. Solved after disabling them.

Answer (score 0):

**THIS IS NOT CORRECT BUT if you do it you're doing under your own risk!!!!!**

I solved this issue changing the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run permission and adding "Everyone" role with all permissions (Remove this permissions when the installation is done)

Hope this is going to work for you.